# Order of function execution - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing an app that notifies people in case of an emergency. For instance, if an alert gets triggered it calls "Function A" which gets all of the users on "Team A" and sends the alert to 2 of them at a time and then it immediately sets an interval to repeat the execution of the function after 10 seconds if nobody has responded to the alert. It keeps repeating this until someone responds or until there are no more users to notify. 
While we wait for someone on "Team A" to respond, the app may decide to call "Function A" again, but this time it will try to reach 2 users on "Team B" and set the interval in the same way it was set in the step above.

My question is: When "Function A" gets called for a second time, will it have any effect (or in other words, will it interrupt) the execution of the function the first time it was called? In other words, will it cause the function to stop notifying users on "Team A" so it can start notifying users on "Team B"?

Right now I have the same function written 2 times, which is totally pointless. I want to know if I can just use one function and call it when it is necessary.

I have read several question on SO about the order of function execution in Node, but I have not been able to find a clear answer for my question.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what's going on without seeing either your code or a trimmed down reproducible example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It would be nice to have an example code. However, each time you call a function, `FunctionA` in this case, you create a new execution stack for that function call. This means you can call `FunctionA` as many times as you want without interrupting other executions. But if `FunctionA` is accessing and mutating variables outside its scope it can cause both calls to have different behavior.

Comment: @huichops I think that you just answered my question. If it creates a new execution stack, it should not interfere then. You just helped me understand something I have been wondering about for a while!